# send and receive sms therough web application

Tags: android, web, sms, message

i need to know is it possible or is there any way to submit a Html form through SMS from an application on android device without internet connection and receive it through SMS and store it on database with my application ?
i know i should have access to local GSM service provides but the main point is about the end users and i should consider that they don't have access to internet and the should be able to send form through SMS, so if you have any idea or solution let me know please.

i found some API and solution for this issue but seems they need to have internet connection for end user:

[smsgateway.me](https://smsgateway.me)

[smssync](http://smssync.ushahidi.com)

[znisms](http://znisms.com)

Comment: Please clarify, do you want to send an SMS from your web service to a users phone or send data in an SMS from an app on a phone to your web service? Or something else entirely?

Comment: both of theme but im not afraid about my side to use internet, i should consider that the user who want to submit form through application dosnt have access to internet and i should find the solution that is there any way to submit form through sms without internet connection? thanks

Comment: You need one of those services to receive an SMS, the service would then notify your own web service with a web request that contains the content of the SMS. In your application you should be able to use the SMS api of your os to send an sms. Can't help you on the application without knowing more about it though. For the reverse, it's basically the same, you use your SMS service to send the SMS to the user and capture it from your app.

Comment: Remember to ask the user if she even wants your app to send an SMS that will probably cost her...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following in application:

1. Get your inputs data first
2. Concatenate them with some delimiter(,_....)
3. Storing all concatenated data to one variable
4. Then send it as body of SMS

In Server side:

1. First get SMS from that port(e.g: 7777)
2. Explode the SMS with delimter(,_....) that concatenated before
3. Store the exploded data in server

But remember it will gets a big cost.

Answer (score 1):

SMS is restricted to 160 characters per SMS. I'm assuming that your subscribers are going to be charged for each SMS (unless you have an agreement with the GSM service provider to zero-rate the SMSs). Generally, the SMSs sent by your application need to be as few as possible. Sending an HTML form is expensive since it sends a lot of useless information.

Do this:

1. Retrieve the user's input to each of the fields in your form
2. Clean and validate the input (Remove extra spaces,validate and reject what you don't need immediately so you don't send stuff you don't need)
3. Combine all the fields into a string separated by whatever separator you want to use, one the user won't have entered in his/her input. Your validation in step 2 can reject user input that uses your separator and offer alternatives
4. Send that as an SMS to your application
5. At your application, split the fields, add the HTML (not sure why you'd want to do this, but working with your question) and store that into your database

Comment: I don't think he wants the HTML transmitted but rather the data from the form just like you explained.